# Agregar items concretos a un array de forma recursiva

Tags: javascript

Está función agrega a un array los items del 1 al `(num)` de forma "recursiva"

```js
array = []

function sumFibs(num) {
  if (num == 0) return 1;
  else if (num == 100) return 1;

  array.push(num)
   return num + sumFibs(num -1 )
 
}

sumFibs(10);
```

Es decir `sumFibs(10)` añade al array vacío:  `array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

`sumFibs(8)` añade al array vacío: `array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

etc...

Pues bien lo que quiero una función recursiva que con el  `array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` devuelva `array nuevo = [2,3,5,8]`

El `array nuevo = [2,3,5,8]` es el resultado de obtener los numeros "fibonacci" del `array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

Comment: 3 veces lo he leido, y aun no lo entiendo. ¿ No podrías poner los datos de entrada y salida que esperas, con algunos pasos intermedios ?

Comment: Lo he editado. Mira a ver que te parece. Realmente lo que quiero es obtener los numeros fibonacci de ese array primario, y guardarlos en un array nuevo.

Comment: Que no, que no te sigo. La [sucesión de Fibonacci](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucesi%C3%B3n_de_Fibonacci) va de sumar de 2 en 2. No me cuadran tus entradas y salidas de ejemplo :-(

Comment: Ah, vale. Ya lo pillo. Creo.

Comment: Lo dices porque he quitado los dos [1,1] que tiene que ir delante?

Comment: Lo que quieres es que, dado un array de números, crear otro donde estén **solo los número que pertenezcan a la sucesión de fibonacci**.

Comment: Es lo único que me cuadra con lo que has puesto.

Comment: @Trauma Si. El caso es que no lo dije así de explícito porque no quería una función que sacase directamente los fibonacci de un número dado. Sino efectivamente primero crear el array de números, y luego crear otro dónde sólo estén los números fibonacci. Pero al final me compliqué de más explicando :S

Comment: Entonces ... ¿ estabas jugando al *despiste* ? Jejeje ... Todo aclarado pues :-)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92696/discussion-between-javier-cake-and-trauma).

Answer (score 1):

Para filtrar un arreglo de números obteniendo solo aquellos que pertenecen a la sucesión de Fibonacci, puedes hacer uso de las fórmulas estándar
[image] y
[image], en donde `N` es el número en sí que deseas comprobar; si la raíz cuadrada de la solución de cualquiera de las dos fórmulas te da un número entero, entonces el número pertenece a la sucesión de Fibonacci.

A continuación te dejo la implementación comprobando los números de un arreglo que contiene los números de 0 a 1.000.000:

```javascript
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks')

// Generador para obtener arreglo de numeros a comprobar
function* range(limit) {
    if (typeof limit === 'number' && Number.isInteger(limit)) {
        for (let idx = 0; idx <= limit; idx = idx + 1) {
            yield idx
        }
    }   else {
        throw new Error('Argument limit must be an integer number')
    }
}

// Funcion encargada de verificar si el numero pertenece a la sucesion de Fibonacci
const isFibNum = (number) => {
    if (typeof number === 'number') {
        if (Number.isInteger(Math.sqrt(5 * (number ** 2) + 4)) ||
            Number.isInteger(Math.sqrt(5 * (number ** 2) - 4))) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }   else {
        throw new Error('Argument number must be a number')
    }
}

const initArray = [...range(1000000)]

const initTime = performance.now()

const fibArray = initArray.filter(val => isFibNum(val))

console.log(fibArray)

const endTime = performance.now()
const elapsedTime = endTime - initTime

console.log(`Elapsed time: ${elapsedTime / 1000}s`)
```